# Green's function of $\frac{d}{dx}\left((1-x^2)\frac{d}{dx}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, greens-function

I want the Green's function of the operator $\frac{d}{dx}\left((1-x^2)\frac{d}{dx}\right)f$, with the boundary conditions $f(0)=f(1)=0$.

I therefore need to solve the equation $\frac{d}{dx}\left((1-x^2)\frac{dG}{dx}\right)=\delta(x-y).$

If $x\neq y$, we have $(1-x^2)\frac{dG}{dx}=c$ with $c$ a constant and 
$$ G=\frac{c}{2}\int\frac{dx}{1-x}+\frac{c}{2}\int\frac{dx}{1+x}=\frac{c}{2}\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)+d.$$

This form is valid both for $x<y$ and $x>y$. Wecan use $c_1,d_1$ in the first domain and $c_2,d_2$ in the other.

Now, I muts impose the boundary conditions. Vanishing at $x=0$ implies $d_1=0$. But vanishing at $x=1$ implies $c_2=d_2=0$. So $G(x,y)=\frac{c_1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$ if $x<y$ and $G(x,y)=0$ if $x>y$.

If I impose continuity at $x=y$, I get $c_1=0$. So $G=0$ everywhere.

This can't be right. What gives?

Comment: The singularity at $x=1$ poses a problem here. Can you work with a discontinuous solution?

Comment: The function $(1-x^2)\frac{dG(x,y)}{dx}$ must must have a unit jump at $x=y$. Can this be achieved with a discontinuous $G$? Wouldn't the jump be infinite in that case?

Comment: You've shown already that it *cannot* be acheived with a continuous $G$. The jump is infinite only when $x=y=1$. I can't think of any other way.

Comment: Why is the jump infinite only when $x=y=1$? I can see $x=y$, but why 1?

Comment: There's only a jump when $x=y$. What happens when you divide out $(1-x^2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot impose traditional endpoint conditions for this equation because the equation is singular at $x=\pm 1$. The solution of $((1-x^2)f')'=0$ have the form that you discovered, which is
$$
             f = C\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}+D.
$$
So there are two arbitrary constants associated with $f$ at each of the two endpoints, but imposing $f(0)=0$ (or $f(1)=0$) requires $C=D=0$. This is because the ODE is singular at $x=\pm 1$. The above may be treated as an asymptotic for homogeneous solutions near the endpoints, and the constants take the place of $f(0),f'(0),f(1),f'(1)$ for a non-singular equation. Physicists typically require boundedness near the endpoints, which forces $C=0$ and allows $D$ to vary, which allows you to construct the Green function.

(As a picky note, it is "Green function" and not "Green's function". It sounds wrong because green is a color, but we say Bessel function or Legendre function, etc., and not Bessel's function(s), etc.)

Comment: I agree that "Green function" makes more sense, but "Green's function" seems to be much more widespread. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: It's actually always been called [Green's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) [function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreensFunction.html), so I don't know where you got that idea from

Comment: @Dylan : If you refer to it as a Green's function, you might want to rethink that construction.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sounded combative. Do you have any reference or sources that say it should be called "Green function" instead?

Comment: @Dylan : The Encyclopedia of Mathematics maintained by Springer Verlag is a possible reference: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Green_function

Comment: @Dylan : It's similar to the Washington Memorial or the Fourier series.